# Value used in the formula is of wrong type

Tags: excel, vba

I am calling UDF function. It is reporting `#value` error which says value used in the formula is of wrong data type. Please find below the code

```
Function pattern(a As Double, x As Range, y As Range) As Double
    Dim i As Integer, x1 As Double, x2 As Double, y1 As Double, y2 As Double

    For i = 0 To x.RowCount
        If x(i) > a Then GoTo Line1
    Next i

    Line1:
    x1 = x(i - 1)
    x2 = x(i)
    y1 = y(i - 1)
    y2 = y(i)

    pattern = y1 + ((y2 - y1) * (a - x1) / (x2 - x1)) 
End Function
```

Comment: First issue I see is that `x.RowCount` does not exist. It should be `x.Rows.Count`. Second issue is that `x2 - x1` might be equal `0` . You do not cover that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Function Pattern(a As Double, x As Range, y As Range) As Double
    Dim i As Integer, x1 As Double, x2 As Double, y1 As Double, y2 As Double

    For i = 1 To x.Rows.Count
        If x(i) > a Then
            x1 = x(i - 1)
            x2 = x(i)
            y1 = y(i - 1)
            y2 = y(i)

            Pattern = y1 + ((y2 - y1) * (a - x1) / (x2 - x1))
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

- The `Range` object (e.g. `x`, `y`) cannot be zero-indexed. So `i = 1 to x.Rows.Count`
- I'd avoid the `GoTo` statement and use `exit function` instead (to exit the loop)

Comment: I am sorry but you are not correct. Although one should not do that but let's take `Range("A3:A4")` and consider `x(-1)`.